Numpy/PyTorch indexing, assigning values over repeats
I am trying to combine assignment and advanced indexing. I have an array of size (batch, x, y, width) and I am trying to assign it to an array of (batch, width) such that the values are repeated over x, y, but my shapes will not broadcast. A slow version of the code looks like
g = x.clone() # size is batch, x, y, width


for i in batch_size:
   g[i, :, :, :] = x[i, goals[i, 1], goals[i, 0], :] # goals is of size (batch_size, 2)


I have attempted to make this code much faster by doing the following:
goal_y = goal[:, 1]
goal_x = goal[:, 0]
g[:, :, :, :] = x[torch.arange(batch_size), goal_y, goal_x, :]

but I get a shape error because we can't broadcast a shape of [batch_size, width] into [batch_size, x, y, width]. The idea here is it would just repeat over the dimension x, y and I can expand x using numpy.repeat but this is kinda gross. Is there a better way to do this? Any help is much appreciated.

The issue with your code is x[torch.arange(batch_size), goal_y, goal_x, :] produces an output tensor of size (bs, width) when your g assignment expects a tensor of shape (bs, x, y, width). Since you want the tensor to repeat over the x and y dimensions, you can add unit axes and use the repeat operator.
Your desired output reassigns every value in g, so unless there's a specific reason to use the same object, you can just do indexing/reshaping and avoid the assignment entirely.
# randomly chooise dimensions
bs, x_dim, y_dim, w_dim = torch.randint(1, 32, (4,))

# randomly sample x and g
x = torch.randn(bs, x_dim, y_dim, w_dim)
g = torch.randn(bs, x_dim, y_dim, w_dim)

# create goals tensor that can index into the second and third dimensions of x
goals = torch.randint(0, min(x.shape[1:3]), (bs, 2)).long()

# reassign values in g the slow way
for i in range(bs):
    g[i] = x[i, goals[i,1], goals[i,0], :]

# index into x for all bs values
# g2 has shape (bs, width)
g2 = x[torch.arange(bs), goals[:,1], goals[:,0]]

# add unit axes
# g2 has shape (bs, 1, 1, width)
g2 = g2[:,None,None,:]

# repeat values of g2 along new axes
# g2 has shape (bs, x, y, width)
g2 = g2.repeat(1, x_dim, y_dim, 1)

# compare values
print((g == g2).all())
> tensor(True)


Yes I agree you can do it this way. I am really trying to avoid any calls to a repeat function for speed. Like I think one way to do what you did is with torch.tile(), but it is essentially calling a repeat. Is there any way to avoid this?

You can replace .repeat(1, x_dim, y_dim, 1) with .expand(bs, x_dim, y_dim, w_dim). expand returns a view rather than a copy so you don't copy data the way repeat does
